# Proving the existence of a complex matrix verifying two conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Let $V,V'$ be two complex row matrices of size $n$ i.e. $V,V'\in \mathcal{M}_{1,n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $V$ and $V'$ are linearly independent.

I wanted to show that there exists $X \in \mathcal{M}_{n,1}(\mathbb{C}) $ such that $VX = 1$ and $V'X=0$.

I wanted to use results on Euclidean spaces but $\mathbb{C}^n$ is only an Euclidean space when seen as a real vector space. If I were working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I would know exactly what to do, but here I need some help to clarify the situation please.

**I only know Euclidean spaces !**

Comment: $VX$ is an inner product?

Comment: @Emilio Novati That's what I thought. Yes but which one?

Comment: I imagine $VX$ is simply the complex number (or $1\times1$ matrix if you like) obtained by the usual matrix multiplication of the row $V$ and the column $X$. Consider $A$ to be the $2\times n$ matrix whose rows are $V$ and $V'$. What is its rank? Is it possible to solve $AX = \big({1\atop0}\big)$?

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you for your answer. Well the rank of $A$ is two because it is the rank of its row vectors. I don't really know how to answer your second question.

Comment: @GregMartin if $a$ canonically represents $A$ then as $\mathrm{rk}(a)=2$, we have $\mathrm{Im}(a) = \mathbb{C}^2$ and we can always find at least one $x$ such that $a(x) = (1,0)$, is that right?

Comment: That is correct!